# How to find rows which unique identifiers exist in a given DataTable in DataGridView?

Tags: winforms

I have a DataGridView which displays the values of the following columns in a table

```
PK1, PK2, PK3, C1, C2, C3, C4
  1,   2,   3,  A,  B,  X,  Y
  4,   1,   4,  C,  D,  Z,  Y (Match the rows in the table below)
  2,   3,   5,  F,  E,  X,  W
  3,   1,   2,  A,  B,  X,  Y (Match the rows in the table below)
  ......
```

`PK1, PK2, PK3` are combined Primary Key of the table. Given a DataTable of the PKs (The example is shown below). What's the best approach to find these rows?

```
PK1, PK2, PK3
  4,   1,   4
  3,   1,   2
```

(iterate DataGridView cells or underline DataSource? Maybe cells since I will need to highlight some cells in the rows. Performance considerations?)

Comment: `What's the best approach to find these rows?` which rows? Where primary key matches?

Comment: @Sami, Yes, need to find the rows and change the format/style of display of some cells.

Comment: Then your given example is incorrect? Or I have not been unable make you clear what I am asking. Because in your given example `4,1,4` can not match `3,1,4`. What type of matching you are taking about?

Comment: They are two sets of PKs. Two rows in the datagridview will be matched, as I wrote on the right part of the first table.

Comment: Rows can be found. What will you do then. Let us say row#3 matches row#8,12,21 and row#6 matches row#15 only. What the output you need? Will you need only pk1,pk2,pk3 of row#3 and row#6 only or you need row# of all matching rows?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [DataGridView RowPrePaint event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint.aspx), [CellFormatting event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint.aspx), or [CellPainting event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting.aspx), to implement the highlighting.

For matching the rows, it kind of matters where the data is coming from.  If it's coming from the same database, could you do the matching in the query that returns the data?  You could use Linq to do a query on the DataTables and find the matches.

Another idea would be to create a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx) between your two DataTables.  See the example on the [DataTable Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) page, near the bottom.  Search on `MakeDataRelation` to find the example. DataRelations can be really tricky, but when you get them working, they're really cool.

To evaluate performance considerations, more information is probably needed.  Where is the data coming from? How many rows of data in each table, a few, 10s, 100s, 1000s?  Do you have any control over the design of your data source?  Could you eliminate this composite key and create a surrogate key?

If you have control over the query, you could do something like:

```
SELECT A.PK1, A.PK2, A.PK3, A.C1, A.C2, A.C3, 
       WHEN B.PK1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS OTHER
FROM TABLEA AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.PK1 = B.PK1 AND A.PK2 = B.PK2 AND A.PK3 = B.PK3
WHERE <whatever other criteria you have for this query>
```

Now the OTHER column in the DataTable would indicate if TableB had a match.  You don't really need the `WHEN...END` clause, you could just put `B.PK1` and deal with null versus a value, assuming that `PK1` would never have a valid value of null.  In your application, don't display the `OTHER` column, just use it as the value that determines whether to do the highlighting or not.

Comment: The data comes from SQL Server. I'm adding a feature to a legacy application. And this feature is not a frequently used feature so I don't want to change the data source. I cannot eliminate the composite key and create surrogate key. They may be 100K rows.

Comment: A couple more questions.  About the data source, do you have control over the query?  Or is this two data tables coming back as one data set from a stored procedure or two stored procedures?

Comment: 100K rows is a lot of rows to be displaying.  Is that the number of rows in the SQL Server table, or in the 'DataTable' returned by the query?  How are you displaying this data?  In a Windows Forms application or in a ASP.NET web app?  Using C# or VB or some other language?  The language doesn't really matter, but it's nice to know what the target is.

Comment: It's from two stored procedures. Normally the grid view will display 10K rows. It's WinForms in C#.

Comment: 10K rows is still a lot of data to display to a user, but okay.  I'm guessing that DataRelations will be the way to go here.  I need to write some test code, then I'll add to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define `DataTable.PrimaryKey()` and then use `DataTable.Rows.Find()`.

[PrimaryKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z24kefs8(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Find a DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx)

Working on datatable is more efficient than DataGridView Cell. I recomend taking care before formating cells, check this
[Using Cell Styles Efficiently](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ha5xt0d9(v=vs.100).aspx)
.